# Play: How to validate a JsValue

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Here is very simple JSON snippet...

```
[
  {
    "email": "fred@flintstones.com",
    "name": "fred",
    "trash": "ignore"
  }
]
```

... that needs to be validated before being processed:

```
val validateUser: Reads[JsValue] = (
  (__ \ 'email).read(email) ~
  (__ \ 'name).read[String]
).tupled ~> implicitly[Reads[JsValue]]
```

The validator works... but the resulting `JsValue` still contains the `trash` field, which should be filtered out instead:

```
scala> val user = Json.obj(
     | "email" -> "fred@flintstones.com",
     | "name" -> "fred", "trash" -> "ignore")
user: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"email":"fred@flintstones.com","name":"fred","trash":"ignore"}

scala> val userValidator: Reads[JsValue] = (
     | (__ \ 'email).read(email) ~
     | (__ \ 'name).read[String]).tupled ~> implicitly[Reads[JsValue]]
userValidator: play.api.libs.json.Reads[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$3$$anon$4@77d7654e

scala> userValidator.reads(user)
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = JsSuccess({"email":"fred@flintstones.com","name":"fred","trash":"ignore"},)
```

Then, I've tried to modify the validator like this...

```
val validateUser: Reads[(String, String)] = (
  (__ \ 'email).read(email) ~
  (__ \ 'name).read[String]
).tupled
```

... and this time the resulting tuple no longer contains the `trash` field as expected:

```
scala> val userValidator: Reads[(String,String)] = (
     | (__ \ 'email).read(email) ~
     | (__ \ 'name).read[String]).tupled
userValidator: play.api.libs.json.Reads[(String, String)] = play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8@24ccd12b

scala> userValidator.reads(user)
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[(String, String)] = JsSuccess((fred@flintstones.com,fred),)
```

Now the questions are: how do I make my validator return a `JsValue` without the `trash` field? Why does `~> implicitly[Reads[JsValue]]` keep it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Dan's and Isammoc's solutions work... but looking at the Json documentation, I think the right way should be as following:

```
val emptyObj = __.json.put(Json.obj())

...

val validateUser = (
  (( __ \ 'email).json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsString] keepAnd Reads.email)) ~
  (( __ \ 'name).json.pickBranch) ~
  (( __ \ 'optional).json.pickBranch or emptyObj)
).reduce
```

As you can see, I've also added email verification and defined `emtpyObj` to simulate `JsPath.readNullable`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the function of the validator isn't to transform the JSON but to validate that it has certain fields and they are of the expected type.

If you want to transform the JSON to remove 'trash', you can:

```
userValidator.reads(user).map(js => js - "trash")
```

or to only include certain fields:

```
userValidator.reads(user).map(js => Json.obj("name" -> js \ "name", "email" -> js \ "email"))
```

You've probably seen [this](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) article but it's so useful I've included it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your parser validate each input and take the original input if it succeed.

Your issue is about JSON transformation (described in the [official documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonTransformers) )

You have to keep only valid input as follow :

```
val validateUser = (
  (( __ \ 'email ).read(email) ~> ( __ \ 'email ).json.pickBranch) ~
  ((__ \ 'name).read[String] ~> ( __ \ 'name ).json.pickBranch)
) reduce
```